# vba autofill column with a specific value

Tags: vba, excel

Any ideas on how can i improve with this codes. I want them to auto fill in the text "hello" instead of copying the value which is at S2. Is there a way that I could let it set the value in instead?

```
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("S2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("S2:S" & lastRow)
```

Comment: Did you try simply `Range("S2:S" & lastRow) = "hello"`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `Autofill`. What you need is `FillDown` like this:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("S2","S" & lastRow).FillDown
End With
```